# XCode 4.6 keeps on downloading Doc Set

Tags: xcode4.6

Since I installed XCode 4.6, it keeps on downloading the Doc Set each and every time I open it. I've seen a lot of threads talking about this topic, so I tried to manually install the doc set in the Developper/Shared/Documenation/Docsets folder. But even with that, I opened XCode this morning and.... it started downloading the thing again. What can I do to make it stop ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click the link under Xcode->Preferences Click on Xcode 4.6 doc set you will see an installed location. click on that link and delete the file. In my case there was another Xcode 4.6 file I think it was called Xcode 4.6 Documentation set I deleted that as well.

I closed XCode and opened up again the told it to download it again and it took.

You should only have one Xcode 4.6 file in your list I had two and I don't know why. Might be something left over from the 4.6 beta.

Hope it help

Answer (score 12):

Go to the "Xcode->Preferences->Downoloads" and unselect the check mark under "Check for and install updates automatically" in the "Documlentation" tab.

Answer (score 4):

## Downloading Fresh Doc

As the other answers suggest, Xcode is merely detecting, downloading, and installing new versions of the documentation available on the Apple servers.

## Disable Auto-Download

As [pablok said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057051/642706), if you don't like this behavior, disable the behavior by unchecking `Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Documentation > Check for and install updates automatically`.

## Fresh Doc Stored Outside App

One interesting twist is that the old versions are stored *inside* Xcode.app while the fresh downloaded versions are stored *outside* the app.

For example, in *Xcode 4.6.3* on Mountain Lion obtained from the developer.apple.com *iOS Dev Center*, the `Xcode 4.6 doc set` is bundled with the Xcode app. That bundled doc set, according to the Finder, is:

- Version: 509.12
- Size: 268.4 MB
- Location: …/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets

The newly downloaded doc set is:

- Version: 511.5
- Size: 286.8 MB
- Location: ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets

So, two mysteries:

- Why does Apple bundle doc inside the app but download new doc somewhere else?
- After doing so, why does Apple leave the old doc in place? Why not delete it?

As an experiment, someday I will delete the original ones inside the app. I'm not suggesting any benefit (other than recovering storage space) nor am I saying there is no adverse effect.